# Is it possible to define limit()'s for child objects?

Tags: firebase

I am looking to retrieve the first 10 records of a 1000 in a dataset, but each of those records has a property with a 1000 records itself - is there a way to limit the grandchild to only return X records as well? Something like:

firebaseRef.limit(10).limit(10, childPropertyName).once(...)

(when I say 1000, it could be 1,000,000, I didn't want to include all the zeros)

If not, are there any workarounds or strategies to deal with large nested sets?

One possibility is to de-nest them. The grandchild could be split out out into its own list with the same key names as its former parent. Is that the best way to go?

Comment: De-nesting is really the best way to go. In some cases, it's usefule to subset all the data. For instance, my "users" have a "profile" section, a "private" section, and several lists. When I retrieve the user data for list purposes, I simply retrieve the "profile". But generally with NoSQL, you want to de-nest.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. We're working on ways to do this but they won't be released for a while.

In the meantime, I'd suggest building a separate index that simply lists the names of the top-level children. Then you can do a "limit(10)" on that index, and then do a limit(10) on a path constructed using each of those keys.

So your code would look like this:

```
indexRef.limit(10).once("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  dataRef.child(snapshot.name()).limit(10).once(...);
}
```

Comment: I'm worried about "event callback is passed a snapshot containing all data at that location, **including child data**". 

If the parent 10 records each had a property with a million records, then this would load 10 million records before it has the opportunity to limit the children to only 10 as well - is that correct?

Comment: Right, that's why I'm suggesting setting up an index -- you would have a separate place in your Firebase that only contains the names for the children but not their data. You would then do the outer "limit()" just on the list of names.